# How do I stop processing rows in Spring-JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a consumer that can say he doesn't want to process more data.

I've looked upon the methods in Spring `JdbcTemplate`, but I see no way to inform Spring I don't want to process more rows when I'm on callback.

I could throw an exception, but then the `jdbcTemplate.query(...)` would rethrow this exception, which is the behavior I don't wish.

Is there any way to force stop processing rows without causing exception?

```
jdbc.query(sql, new RowCallbackHandler() {

  @Override
  public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
  {
    // TODO how to stop if I want to do it here?
  }}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

(If somebody comes to this thread) - Use ResultSetExtractor.
Loop through resultset in while condition and break out when needed.

```
Set<String> distinctNames = jdbcTemplate.query(query,
new ResultSetExtractor<Set<String>>(){
    public Set<String> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        Set<String> distinctNames = new HashSet<>();
        Integer cacheMax = 1000
        while(rs.next() && distinctNames.size() <= cacheMax){   
        // magic is in while loop condition to break out when we want ignoring rest of results from DB.
            distinctNames.add(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        }
        return distinctNames;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into:

- [setFetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int))
- [setMaxRows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int))

> **jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(intValue):** Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when
>   more rows are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement.
>   If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored. The default
>   value is zero.
>
> **jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(intValue):** Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any ResultSet object generated by this Statement
>   object can contain to the given number. If the limit is exceeded, the
>   excess rows are silently dropped.

I think that **jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(intValue)** could be helpful for your requirements.

Comment: Those parameters are taken into account **before** and not **during** processing...